# vmware: how to virtualize nt server 4.0?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, consolidation

I'm trying to virtualize a nt server 4.0 sp1.  When I run the vmware converter it says that is must be at least sp3.  However I can't even find this on MSDN.  Has anyone had a similar experience and found a relatively painless solution. I'm trying not to reinvent the wheel here.  Thanks

Comment: You... want to what?

Comment: Why don't you install SP3?

Comment: By the $dieties, WHY?!

Comment: I assume you mean COBOL, and in that case, brace yourself.  It probably predates 1990 by a number of *decades*.

Comment: @HopelessN00b cobol right, yeah wow even older then I thought then

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While echoing the "this should have been destroyed years ago" sentiment, you can download NT 4.0's various service packs at the ftp link below.  (The installer .exes for the Service Packs are under the relevant i386 directory, as is the Windows way.)

ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/bussys/winnt/winnt-public/fixes/usa/nt40/

(Hotfixes too, and even what passed for NT utilities, back in the day.)

Comment: Eh? I didn't post a download link.

Comment: @MichaelHampton  Yeah, I edited my edit after re-reading your post.  Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: @HopelessN00b just what I was looking all over for Thanks

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna  Glad I could help.  Hope you make a mint working with that old PoS, as is deserved for such a horrific task.

Answer (score 5):

[The latest Windows NT 4.0 service pack](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/152734) is Service Pack 6a.

Microsoft no longer distributes NT 4.0 service packs on its Web site, though as @HopelessN00b noted in his answer, they can still be found on [MS's FTP site](ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/bussys/winnt/winnt-public/fixes/usa/nt40/).

Finally, whatever it is probably should have been decommissioned years ago. [All support for Windows NT 4.0 ended in 2004](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?LN=en-us&x=20&y=7&p1=3188).

Comment: The link on the first URL just goes to a page telling you "tough titties, you're out of support" with no downloads

Comment: Actually, all prior SPs are available... maybe just not on the web. ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/bussys/winnt/winnt-public/fixes/usa/nt40/  MS's ftp site is a veritable treasure trove of ancient, unsupported code that should have been thrown away ages ago... but very handy for making $$$$ off those clients who just insist on running that [whatever legacy crap] for [whatever stupid reason].

Comment: I bow down to you Mr.HopelessN00b!  Seriously, didn't know MS kept this stuff on their FTP site.  Wow.

Comment: Couln't help myself... there's Exchange 4.0, 5.0 and 5.5 on there too.  Just as I was about to embark on an Exchange 2013 POC.  I could just go retro!

Answer (score 0):

Can't stop smiling about this one.  You're right, most P2V tools require SP3 onwards.  Looks like even the terminal service pack (6A) no longer exists on MS's site (no suprise there then!).  However, a quick google brought be to:

[http://web.archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20060702015605/http://www.microsoft.com/ntserver/nts/downloads/recommended/SP6/128bitX86/default.asp)

Now, I've heard of this site before, but do not know whether the files on there are genuine files.  Download at your own risk!

Comment: They should be accurate, but archive.org don't archive files over a certain size. Service Packs are probably too large for them to have kept.

Comment: Ahh... Rememebr when the NT SP and the TS SP were different animals?

Comment: Remember having to reinstall the SP after installing a system component?

Answer (score -1):

How about using Clonezilla and VMware Server to make the PC an image and then convert the Clonezilla image to a VM, here are the instructions on how to do it via ibm.com

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-clonezilla/index.html?ca=dgr-lnxw100Clonezilla&S_TACT=105AGX59&S_CMP=grlnxw100

Comment: -1 VMWare Server has been EOL for years now.

Comment: touche, how about VMware Player instead, either way once he has the ISO of PC created with Clonezilla he can load it in any software capable of handling/creating VMs.